# How to add nested tables into existing table of PDF in iText using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The following code below gives me a table in iText.

However, I would like to also add two further columns to the right of the table; one which shows another '=' sign, (basically exactly the same as the 2nd column of the existing table) and then to the right of that I would like to add another column showing an 'a' (the same as the 1st column of the existing table).

So really I want to take my existing table and add the 2nd and 1st column onto the end of it in that order so I finish with a table with 5 columns. Do I need to produce a nested table for this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
PdfPTable table0 = new PdfPTable(3);

float[] widths = new float[] { 7f, 0.5f, 4f };

table0.SetWidths(widths);

PdfPCell cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a"));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" = "));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("b"));
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("c"));
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

document.Add(table0);
```

Comment: *"I want to take my existing table and add ..."* - By this you mean that you have the `table0` object as it is right before adding it to the `document`? Or have you already added it to the `document` but not yet closed that `document`? Or have you already closed the `document` so that all you have is the PDF that displays that table?

Comment: Hi, I have opened the document, and then I have added the code above and then closed the document. This means that when I run the program (press f5), it generates a PDF which has a table with 3 columns. But I need to add some code to the code above to paste into my C# program so that when I press f5, it generates a PDF with 5 columns as I describe above.

Comment: So if you want to create PDFs with tables with more columns, why don't you add more columns in your code above?

Comment: I need it so that the table has 2 rows, when I try adding more code it just gives the table 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *"add the 2nd and 1st column onto the end of"* your table, you need to:

- initialize the `PdfPTable table0` for two more columns;
- extend the `float[] widths` to contain widths for two more columns; and
- add the cells for two more columns.

E.g. like this:

```
PdfPTable table0 = new PdfPTable(5);

float[] widths = new float[] { 7f, 0.5f, 4f, 0.5f, 7f };

table0.SetWidths(widths);

PdfPCell cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a"));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" = "));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("b"));
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" = "));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a"));
cell0.Rowspan = 2;
cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("c"));
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right            
table0.AddCell(cell0);

document.Add(table0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing: do you know how I can show the '=' sign in the 2nd and 4th column with a vertical alignment in the center? When I run the code above it shows the '=' sign at the bottom of the cell (i.e. the equivalent of being in row 2), despite the fact that I am using: cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

Comment: The cause is that there is more than the `=` sign: You have surrounded it by spaces. The vertical alignment centers that whole `" = "` string, and depending on how that string is broken across lines, the `=` may find itself off-center. If you use `"="` instead, it's centered again as desired.

Comment: OK I should have spotted that! Thanks again mkl!

Comment: If this resolves your issue, please consider marking the answer as accepted (click the tick at its upper left).